# System sound doesn't work properly

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I tried to implement a `speech recognizer` in the background.

And it works all fine. The service runs in background and listens to words the user say.

**My problem is:**

If a music player is running and the speech recognizer restarts, the system sound stream is muted to prevent the beep sound of speech recognition. But muting this stream paues and mutes the music player, too.

Does anyone have an idea how to prevent the beep sound without muting the whole system?

I already tried to mute another stream but the system stream is the only one muting the beep.
and is there any way too pause and resume background Speech recognition when when system Sound in progress. and I am unable to hear alaram sound also

I test on a Nexus 4 with Android 5.1

Best regards.

```
public class MyService extends Service implements SpeechDelegate, Speech.stopDueToDelay {


    public static SpeechDelegate delegate;


    //
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


        //TODO do something useful
        try {
            if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                ((AudioManager) Objects.requireNonNull(
                        getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE))).setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, false);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Speech.init(this);
        delegate = this;
        Speech.getInstance().setListener(this);

        if (Speech.getInstance().isListening()) {
            Speech.getInstance().stopListening();
            muteBeepSoundOfRecorder();
        } else {
            System.setProperty("rx.unsafe-disable", "True");
            RxPermissions.getInstance(this).request(permission.RECORD_AUDIO).subscribe(granted -> {
                if (granted) { // Always true pre-M
                    try {
                        Speech.getInstance().stopTextToSpeech();
                        Speech.getInstance().startListening(null, this);
                    } catch (SpeechRecognitionNotAvailable exc) {
                        //showSpeechNotSupportedDialog();

                    } catch (GoogleVoiceTypingDisabledException exc) {
                        //showEnableGoogleVoiceTyping();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.permission_required, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            muteBeepSoundOfRecorder();
        }
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        //TODO for communication return IBinder implementation
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartOfSpeech() {
      }

    @Override
    public void onSpeechRmsChanged(float value) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSpeechPartialResults(List<String> results) {
        for (String partial : results) {
            Log.d("Result", partial + "");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onSpeechResult(String result) {
       }
    @Override
    public void onSpecifiedCommandPronounced(String event) {
        try {
            if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                ((AudioManager) Objects.requireNonNull(
                        getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE))).setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (Speech.getInstance().isListening()) {
            muteBeepSoundOfRecorder();
            Speech.getInstance().stopListening();
        } else {
            RxPermissions.getInstance(this).request(permission.RECORD_AUDIO).subscribe(granted -> {
                if (granted) { // Always true pre-M
                    try {
                        Speech.getInstance().stopTextToSpeech();
                        Speech.getInstance().startListening(null, this);
                    } catch (SpeechRecognitionNotAvailable exc) {

                    } catch (GoogleVoiceTypingDisabledException exc) {
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.permission_required, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            muteBeepSoundOfRecorder();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to remove the beep sound of voice recognizer.
     */

    private void muteBeepSoundOfRecorder() {
        AudioManager amanager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if (amanager != null) {

          amanager.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM,true);




        }

    }




    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        //Restarting the service if it is removed.
        PendingIntent service =
                PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), new Random().nextInt(),
                        new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        assert alarmManager != null;
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 1000, service);
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }



}
```

Comment: What are SpeechDelegate, Speech, SpeechRecognitionNotAvailable, GoogleVoiceTypingDisabledException. They don't seem to be part of Android, i.e. your question does not have the necessary detail nor correct tagging.

Comment: SpeechDelegate , speech to text i.e google voice typing.

Comment: is it possible to  pause my application when media player is running and when media player stops my app need to resume or restart?